# Does AppEngine HR Datastore auto assign negative IDs?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am using AppEngine with the HR Datastore and my Objects have IDs of type `Long` (using Java). I do not set the ID myself but let the Datastore choose a new unique one. So far I have only seen positive IDs generated.

Does AppEngine also assign negative IDs ever? (assuming that I do not request more than 2^63 IDs of course ;-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be: MAYBE.

In my tests I have only seen positive auto generated IDs, but I was able to store negative IDs (if manually assigned). Until someone can point us to a specification that defines otherwise or at least some Googler from the AppEngine team speaks up, we must assume that they at least reserve the right to generate negative IDs at any time. Thus our code cannot assume generated IDs to be positive always.

Answer (score 1):

[allocate_id_range](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions#allocate_id_range) (the Python method to preallocate ids) will throw an exception if you pass it negative values. So I guess that a negative id key is not a valid one.

Comment: I was able to store an Object with negative ID using Java, so the AppEngine Datastore itself DOES support negative IDs. The question whether or not they generate them is not yet answered though.

Answer (score 0):

No. Only positive IDs will be generated.

Comment: I agree with Daniel, if we are going to assume this in our code we need to see a spec that states it for us so we know we won't get surprised in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In GAE datastore object two unique values are generated, 
one is **KEY**, which is generated when you create instance of your model object, & after saving(put) operation, it generated **ID**(Always would be a positive number), And yes ofcourse both would be unique in whole datastrore.

Comment: You say: "Always would be a positive number". How do you know that? Is that guaranteed? If so, could you please reference the docs / specs?